# Using Generics to minimize repeated code C#

Tags: c#, generics, dynamic, types

I have 3 classes Manager, TeamLead, Employee. These are generated from Database as I am using Entity framework. I can't do any changes here.

```
Class Manager()
{
string AddressLine1;
string AddressLine2;
string AddressLine3;
.
.
//Some other props
}

Class TeamLead()
{
string AddressLine1;
string AddressLine2;
string AddressLine3;
.
.
//Some other props
}

Class Employee()
{
string AddressLine1;
string AddressLine2;
string AddressLine3;
.
.
//Some other props
}
```

Now I another class in some other assembly,

```
Class AddressDetails
{
string AddressLine1;
string AddressLine2;
string AddressLine3;
}
```

And the current piece of code is,

```
Class WorkingPlace
{
Manager _manager;
TeamLead _teamLead;
Employee _employee;
// all the above obejects getting filled in various functions in this class

AddressDetails _addressDetails;

private SomeMethod1()
{
.
.
//doing some works
.
.

FillAddress("Manager");
}

private SomeMethod2()
{
.
.
//doing some works
.
.

FillAddress("TeamLead");
}

private FillAddress(string type)
{
if(type == "Manager")
{
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = _manager.AddressLine1;
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = _manager.AddressLine1;
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = _manager.AddressLine1;

}
else if( type == "TeamLead")
{
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = _teamLead.AddressLine1;
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = _teamLead.AddressLine1;
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = _teamLead.AddressLine1;

}

}
}
```

I want this to be,

```
FillAddress<T>(T typeObj)
{
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = typeObj.AddressLine1;
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = typeObj.AddressLine1;
_addressDetails.AddressLine1 = typeObj.AddressLine1;

}

//and Call it as,

FillAddress<Manager>(_manager);
```

Is it possible, I am new to Generics, I want to code effectively. Experts please help me. any other comments other than this let me know.

Comment: Declare an interface that gives access to these properties and use this for your FillAddress method instead of a concrete type. Or simplify your code, have 1 address type and reuse it, instead of redeclaring new types with the same properties all over the place.

Comment: You can do that using Generic class and reflection. But cannot post my answer which might help you

Comment: I have fixed the issue using reflection. Thanks all :)

Comment: Look into partial classes in entity framework.  As many people have mentioned, you want to add an interface (IAddressDetails or something) to your Manager, TeamLead, and Employee classes.  Using partial classes allows you to add your custom code to the generated code i.e. `public partial class Manager : IAddressDetails {}` will modify the manager class to implement the IAddressDetails interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i see your implementation, you may need to use some reflection. Assuming you have already instantiated `_addressDetail`, you could do something like this:

```
void FillAddress<T>(T value){

   var typeInfo = typeOf(value);

  _addressDetails.AddressLine1 = typeInfo.GetProperty("AddressLine1")?.GetValue(value) as string;
  _addressDetails.AddressLine2 = typeInfo.GetProperty("AddressLine2")?.GetValue(value) as string;
  _addressDetails.AddressLine3 = typeInfo.GetProperty("AddressLine3")?.GetValue(value) as string;

}
```

Comment: I have modified the code using reflection. It is working.. Thanks a lot :-)

Answer (score 2):

Not answering the question, but I see a need for the code to be refactored,
TO avoid repetitive code here,
Consider creating Address class an adding that as a reference in all the other classes

```
Class AddressDetails
{
   string AddressLine1;
   string AddressLine2;
   string AddressLine3;
}
```

Then make your other classes like,

```
class Manager 
{
   AddressDetails address;
   public Manager(AddressDetails address){
      this.address=address;
   }
}

class Employee
{
   AddressDetails address;
    public Manager(AddressDetails address){
      this.address=address;
   }
}
```

Even better, Use base class for all you Employees, as Manager and TeamLead all are employees and all have an address. Let others derive from it.

Now to answer your question, derive an interface from AddressDetails class and let your other classes implement it. Then create your generic method

```
FillAddress(IAddressable employee, Addresdetails newAddress)
{
     employee.AddresssLine1=newAddress.AddressLine1;
      ..........
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the code refactor suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-methods) is a good MSDN article about generic methods.  It should explain everything you need to know.

To answer your question:

**Yes**, that is possible.

The way you formatted your guess at a generic method is correct.  Also, you can omit the `<T>` part, as described by the aforementioned article, as the compiler will infer the type from the arguments.

Comment: Sure I will go through the article. Thank you :-)